# How to use mailto: with url encoded string

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode, mailto

I need to manage mailto protocol with this string:

```
mailto:sales@myweb.co.uk?subject=Something%20from%20Random%20Thing%20app
```

I'm doing with this code:

```
if parameter.hasPrefix("mailto") {
    let urlString = parameter.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    if let url = URL(string: urlString ?? ""), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: L10n.error, message: L10n.notSupportEmail, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        SectionManager.sharedInstance.navigationController?.topViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When the mail app is opened, the subject still contains the "%20" encoded spaces.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Did you try string substitution, and change the %20 sub strings to spaces?

Comment: @DavidH I need a generalistic solution which works with any encoded string, not only with this sample string

Comment: There are multiple ways to un-urlencode strings - I just don’t have one handy to recommend. Pretty sure you can find one by searching.

Comment: Use `removingPercentEncoding` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409569-removingpercentencoding